# Make tkinter toplevel window that doesn't close with parent

Tags: python, tkinter

How should I spawn child `Toplevel()` windows in tkinter that don't close when the parent closes?

Do I need to have the parent keep a 'reference count' of child windows, intercept `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` and only call `root.destroy()` when all the children are gone?

Or is it acceptable practice to spawn another <strike>thread</strike> process with its own tk `mainloop`?

Or is there a more elegant way?

**EDIT**

I am currently doing things this way

```
root = Tk()
app = App(root) # doesn't call Toplevel()
root.mainloop()
```

where `App.__init__()` adds widgets to `root` without calling `Toplevel()`, and at some point spawns a new window with this function:

```
def new_window():
    root = Tk()
    window = App2(root) # doesn't call Toplevel() either
```

Note that `root` in `new_window()` is a different variable to the original `root`, obtained by another call to `Tk()`.

All this seems to Do The Right Thing i.e. the child window lives independently of the parent and the python process dies after both are closed.

So my question becomes, does that make sense or am I doing something horribly wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having to keep track of which Toplevels are alive, you could use a [weakref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref) on a sentinel -- just some object that is passed to each Toplevel and saved in a reference. When each Toplevel dies (is closed), let it delete its reference to the sentinel. When the last reference to the sentinel is deleted, the weakref callback, `self.no_sentinel` will be called automatically, in turn calling `root.destroy` for you.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import weakref


class Sentinel(object):
    pass


class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, sentinel, **kwargs):
        title = kwargs.pop('title')
        self.sentinel = sentinel
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.ondelete)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=title)
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def ondelete(self):
        self.destroy()
        del self.sentinel


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        sentinel = Sentinel()
        parent = Window(master, sentinel, title='Parent')
        child = Window(master, sentinel, title='Child')
        self._ref = weakref.ref(sentinel, self.no_sentinel)            
        # When we exit `__init__` only two strong references to sentinal
        # remain -- in parent and child. When both strong references are
        # deleted, `self.no_sentinel` gets called.
    def no_sentinel(self, *args):
        self.master.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, you *could* use the `multiprocessing` module to spawn another process to make another Tkinter window and mainloop, but would be consumer more memory than the solution above, and would require you to setup some form of interprocess communication if you wanted the separate processes to share information.

Comment: I am now obtaining a new root with `tk.Tk()` but not calling `mainloop()` again - this seems to work while being much simpler - any idea why that might be?  You'd think `Tk()` would be a singleton returning the same master, but creating widgets on it doesn't seem to affect the first window.

Comment: Btw see my edit to original question - I meant process not thread.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. There is a much simpler way than what I show above -- just use Toplevels and call `root.withdraw()` -- but then you can close all your Toplevels and the program will still run in the background. You'll accumulate zombie processes that way. The purpose of the rigmarole above is to cause the program to end when the last Toplevel is closed. If I'm not answering your question, please post your code.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your edited question. I know [the documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x59-details.htm) says, "You should only create one root widget for each program", but I don't know what (if anything) goes wrong if you do call `tk.Tk()` more than once (while calling `root.mainloop` only once).